# How to access other rows around current in r lm() function

Tags: r

I have an array object containing 3 columns and a ton of rows.

Example nonsensical data to show the format:

```
Name  |  Owner  |  Price
chair |  roger  |  50
table |  roger  |  150
sofa  |  bill   |  500
```

I want to use the lm function to get stats about the price column. My problem is, my formular needs to compare the current value to the last value, skipping the very first row completely.

Right now I have

```
lm(My_Function(Price, 5)~., data=myArray)
```

This allows me to do whatever logic I need with the price values. But I need to get the Price, and also the price of the previous row, in `My_Function`, to allow for some comparison logic.

How could I do that?

My code should look sort of like this

```
lm(My_Function(Price, previousPrice, 5)~., data=myArray)
```

So I need two things:

1. How to get the previous value (or any other arbitrary index's value
   during the logic, in relation to the current one)
2. How to skip the
   very first row, without losing its data of course (since it will be
   the "previous" data for the next row)

Comment: Have you considered making a fourth column with lagged values, then referencing that in your lm()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's code which implements Robert Tan's suggestion:

```
# Make example data
X = data.frame("Price" = rnorm(10),
               "Owner" = sample(c("roger", "bill"), 10, replace = T)) 

# Lag the price variable
library(Hmisc)
X$previousPrice = Lag(X$Price, shift = 1) #shift gives number of lags
X #Note first value for previousPrice is NA

#  Run linear model. Note the first row will be ignored from the model as the "lagging" generates an NA
f = lm(Price ~ previousPrice, data = X)
summary(f)
```

Note that this approach will solve both of your questions: (1) is addressed by the lag function; (2) happens automatically because `lm()` will omit the first row because `X$previousPrice` has an `NA` for the first value.

If the above approach doesn't solve your problems and you still need to explicitly call `My_Function()` on an object with the first row removed, you could do the following:

```
My_Function = function(x1, x2) {x1 - x2} #Just for illustration
X2 = X[complete.cases(X), ] #make copy of X with first row removed (NB you could use `X[-1, ]` but complete.cases() will remove *all* rows with NAs)
lm(My_Function(X2$Price, X2$previousPrice) ~ ., data = X2)
```